# to bring/wheel someone in

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a verb synonymous to bringing someone in to demonstrate something. As in:

“To prove their point in front of the judge, the the defense [brought in] an “expert” who was supposed to…“

I’m looking for an expressive idiomatic verb that would capture the obvious cynicality (and perhaps ridiculousness) of this gesture; something similar to “wheel in”, "push in" etc

Answer (score 3):

If the connotation here is that the expert was brought in to say their spiel and put on a show, you can use:

> **trot out**: to bring something out or display something, especially in
>   the expectation of gaining admiration or approval.

If the connotation is that experts were "pushed in", in the sense that they were not there entirely willingly, you can use:

> **drag in**: to involve an unwilling person in a particular situation.
>
> **cart in**: convey (someone) somewhere unceremoniously.
>
> **haul in**: pull or drag with effort or force.

(definitions from ODO)